# running a mysql count command within a looped drop down function

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I have created a drop down box that is populated from a mysql database of primary catagories. When a selection is made, an AJAX function is called which runs a query to display all the sub catagories.

For example,

Primary_catagory = p

sub_catagory = s

p s

1 a

1 b

1 c

2 d

2 e

2 f

so when a selection is made in the primary category, it will show either a,b and c OR d, e and f depending on if 1 or 2 is selected. The query all works fine except from a final cosmetic feature, to show the number of sub categories contained within the primary one.

so the drop down box would show as Choice A (3) and Choice B (2) for example.

This is the code I have so far, but currently it displays (1) for every result. This is the code as it stands.

```
<select id="p_catagory" name="p_catagory" onchange = "getData(this); return true;" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:10px;width:315px;height:20px;z-index:11;text-align:left;">

if ($_GET['p_catagory'] == "all") {
    <option value='all'>Show All</option>
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories WHERE primary_catagory=".$var;
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
    $entries = count($result2);

    echo "<option value='" . $row['primary_catagory'] . "'>" 
         . $row['primary_catagory'] . " " . "(" . $entries . ")" 
         . "</option>";    
}
?>
</select>
```

Ive been on this for days and cant seem to find a work around, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell what value the `$var` variable has - I can't figure it out from the code.

Comment: That variable is the primary category got that loop, Whoops! typo. that line should read    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM db_class_catagories WHERE primary_catagory=".$row['primary_catagory'];

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use:

`$entries = mysqli_num_rows($result2);`

instead of the old line:

`$entries = count($result2);`

I think it should help.

Comment: I used the mysql command initially and it displayed nothing, I couldn't work out why as it was writing as you have above. Is there anything within a loop that could interfere

Answer (score 0):

The array function `count()` or `sizeof()` will not work with the code below as you have it.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);
$entries = count($result2);
```

This is because `mysqli_query()` doesn't return an array, it rather returns a resource which you can use to fetch the result;

To get the number of rows returned, you can do this

```
$records = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$entries = count($records);
```

A shorter method will be

```
$entries = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
```